# What exactly is the purpose of Gsettings? Do I need this?

Tags: linux, gsettings, glib

Accordingly to the documentation, GSettings is:

```
GSettings are a nice way to manage your application’s settings. Those settings are stored in binary form for fast retrieval, and can be manipulated outside of your application as well using specific tools.
```

That tells me a lot but at the same it doesn't tell me nothing. Do I need gsettings at all? What apps are using this? What is the difference between gsettings and glib2? What do I have a bunch of schemas for software that I don't even have installed? If I run `gsettings list-schemas` I see schemas of apps that are not installed in my computer, that is very annoying.

Comment: It depends on you need any app who relies on gsettings. I can't give you a full list. The former was part of the latter. You have some software installed which needs those schemas.

Comment: `gilb2` provides the `gsettings` executable.